# What is the phase space volume in terms of angular momentum?

Tags: partition-function, phase-space

Given a rigid rotor Hamiltonian, defined along the principle axes as
$$ H = \sum_{i=1}^3 \frac{L_i^2}{2I_i} $$

say we would like to compute the classical partition function of this system. Is the proper phase space density give as (?)
\begin{equation} \frac{1}{h^3}\iiint_{-\infty}^{\infty} dL_1dL_2dL_3\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\int_0^{\pi}\sin\theta\ d\theta \end{equation}

I see the dimensionality seems fine, and we are integrating over all possible momentums and rotational positions. Any insight on how we may transform from $f(\vec p,\vec q)$ to $f(\vec L,\vec q')$ may be helpful.

Comment: the phase-space measure is just $\mathrm dp_x\mathrm dp_y\mathrm dp_z\mathrm dx\mathrm dy\mathrm dz$. To express this in other coordinates (eg angular momentum) you just need the [Jacobian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) of the transformation.

Comment: As @AccidentalFourierTransform mentioned, you need the Jacobian. Besides, when you are using the $r,\theta, \phi$ coordinates, then the canonical conjugate momentum is the angular momentum itself.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform That's not quite right, though, because the motion is restricted in both $\vec r$ and $\vec p$.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I... why is it restricted?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Because it's a rigid rotor, i.e. described by a point in $\mathbb R^3$ restricted to a sphere of fixed radius. Thus $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ is constrained, and its momentum vanishes. To fix this you need to go back to the lagrangian and implement the constraint there before going to the hamiltonian formulation.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty but a rigid rotor is, by definition, just a non-deformable object that rotates. I don't see why this implies that its position has to be restricted to the surface of a sphere ($r^2=x^2+y^2+z^2$ is a restriction to its position in space, because $\boldsymbol r$ is the position of the centre of mass of the rotor, and not a vector that encodes its orientation).

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Apologies, there is indeed some ambiguity to the term. The term 'rigid rotor' is often used in the sense of *linear* rigid rotor; it can also conceivably be understood as "a non-deformable object that rotates", also known as a rigid [*top*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top) whose configuration space is $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ rather than $\mathbb S^2$. The OP's use of $\mathbb S^2$ integration supports the first meaning, but Lone Wolf should clarify. In any case, the configuration and phase spaces for the rigid top are rather more complicated than your description.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty yes: I assumed that the conf. space was $\mathrm{SO}(3)$; the fact that OP didn't write an integral over $\mathrm dr$ made me feel a bit uneasy though. Anyway, if his/her configuration space is $\mathbb S^2$ then he/she should integrate over $\frac{1}{h^2}\mathrm dp_\theta\mathrm dp_\phi\mathrm d\theta\mathrm d\phi$, and not what he/she wrote.

Comment: If I am to integrate over the three principle axes, then I assume my configuration space should be $SO(3)$?

Comment: Body fixed axes, that is.